# issue with setting up test framwork with karma, jasmine 2.0, requirejs and angular

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

i am trying to setup testing framework with karma, jasmine 2.0, requirejs and angular. but when i run 'karma start', i got 'Uncaught Error: Module name "shelljs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])'. i have no idea why is that. anybody can help me out? thanks.

my fold structure:

```
$ tree
.
|-- index.html
|-- karma.conf.js
|-- app
|   |-- bower_components
        |-- angular
        |-- requirejs
        |-- angular-mocks
        |-- jasmine
        |-- ...
    |-- scripts
        |-- model
            |-- User.js
        |-- main.js
        |-- ...
-- test
    |-- spec
    |-- model
        |-- userSpec.js
    |-- test-main.js
```

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jun 02 2014 09:54:34 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

            // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
            basePath: '',


            // frameworks to use
            // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
            frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

            // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
            files: [
                {pattern: 'app/bower_components/**/*.js', included: false},
                {pattern: 'app/scripts/*.js', included: false},
                {pattern: 'app/scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
                {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
                {pattern: 'test/test-main.js', included: true},

            ],


            // list of files to exclude
            exclude: [
                'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
                'app/bower_components/**/main.js',
                'app/scripts/main.js',
                'app/scripts/*min.js',
                'app/scripts/**/*min.js'
            ],


            // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
            // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
            preprocessors: {

            },


            // test results reporter to use
            // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
            // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
            reporters: ['progress'],


            // web server port
            port: 9876,


            // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
            colors: true,


            // level of logging
            // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
            logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


            // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
            autoWatch: true,


            // start these browsers
            // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
            browsers: ['Chrome'],
            /*browsers: ['Chrome', 'IE', 'PhantomJS', 'Safari', 'Firefox'],*/

            plugins: [
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-firefox-launcher',
                'karma-IE-launcher',
                'karma-PhantomJS-launcher',
                'karma-script-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-requirejs'
            ],

            // Continuous Integration mode
            // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
            singleRun: false`enter code here`
        }
    )
    ;
    console.log('karma config done--------------------------------');
}
```

;

test-main.js：

```
var allTestFiles = [];
/*var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;*/
//Replace this line with something more specific to your project and make sure it does not match files in your libraries:
var TEST_REGEXP = /spec\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function (path) {
    return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
    /*
     console.log(file);
     */
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(file);
        //allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));


    }
});

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base/app/scripts',

    paths: {
        /*'require': '../bower_components/requirejs/require',*/
        'domReady': '../bower_components/requirejs-domready/domReady',
        'jquery': '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'angular': '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angularResource': '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource',
        'angularTranslate': '../bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate',
        'uiBootstrap': '../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls',
        'uiRouter': '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
        'angularGrid': '../bower_components/angular-grid/build/ng-grid',
        'stacktrace': '../bower_components/stacktrace/stacktrace',
        'angularMocks': '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
        'jasmine': '../bower_components//jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine'
    },

    // angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim: {
        'angular': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'angular'},
        'angularResource': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'angularTranslate': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'uiBootstrap': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'uiRouter': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'angularGrid': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'angularMocks': {deps: ['angular'], 'exports': 'angularMocks'}
    },
    // dynamically load all test files
    deps: allTestFiles,

    // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
    callback: window.__karma__.start


});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "0.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-newer": "0.5.4",
    "grunt-ngmin": "0.0.2",
    "grunt-rev": "0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "0.1.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "0.3.0",
    "time-grunt": "0.2.1",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "0.1.0",
    "requirejs": "2.1.9",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "0.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "0.1.0",
    "grunt-bower-install": "0.7.0",
    "yo": "1.1.2",
    "bower": "1.2.8",
    "generator-karma": "0.6.0",
    "generator-angular": "0.7.1",
    "generator-generator": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.8.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-script-launcher": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0",
    "glob": "^4.0.2",
    "karma": "^0.12.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

bower.json：

```
{
  "name": "myEmail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.14",
    "json3": "3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "2.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.14",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.14",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.14",
    "angular-route": "1.2.14",
    "bootstrap": "3.1.1",
    "respond": "1.4.2",
    "requirejs": "2.1.11",
    "requirejs-domready": "2.0.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.10",
    "angular-translate": "2.0.1",
    "angular-http-auth": "1.2.1",
    "angular-grid": "2.0.7",
    "jquery": "1.11.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
    "stacktrace": "0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.14",
    "jasmine": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Post a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue, since I am running into the same one now?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when my TEST_REGEXP in karma.conf.js was not specific enough and pulled in 'my_client/app/bower_components/jasmine/src/core/Spec.js:1' as a spec file to execute. Once I made sure the TEST_REGEXP was only capturing my specs, this error disappeared. (Presumably the issue is that any specs not actually defined as AMD will have dependency problems.)

So my general pattern for specs is "original_file_name.spec.js". Switching

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /spec\.js$/i;
```

to

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /\.spec\.js$/i;
```

properly catches that pattern. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should have "shelljs": "^0.2.6" inserted in your package.json file